# Spring Batch with very old JDBC 1.0 driver

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I'm working a difficult [enterprise integration](http://eaipatterns.com/eaipatterns.html) scenario involving an antiquated version of [IEX TotalView](http://www.nice.com/iex-totalview) (3.12.6.0.8).  The ODBC driver only works on 32-bit architectures - fine, I'm using Java anyway.  But the Simba RPC-based JDBC driver is only JDBC 1.0 compliant and is limited in many ways that I don't have fully documented (one deficiency is that it appears to not support prepared statements, at least not very well).

I'm trying to use [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) and Apache Camel to build a bridge for extracting WFM data from IEX, but I'm hitting a lot of bumps in the road.  For example, [JdbcCursorItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) fails under:

```
preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(
    sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

… with `java.sql.SQLException: Driver Not Capable`.  I've gotten by in simpler ETL scenarios using [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) with a [`RowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html), but this combination leaves me either driving the extraction myself (defeating the purpose of Spring Batch), or else loading the entire result set into a List (defeating the purpose of paging/streaming).

Right now I'm trying to use a [`JdbcPagingItemReader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) by extending [`AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider.html) to implement my own [query-based paging strategy](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/21383), but it's proving more difficult than anticipated.

I'm new to Spring Batch, so I could be overlooking something.  Does anyone else have any strategies for leveraging Spring with old/deficient/defective JDBC drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I decided to grow my own [`ItemReader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) bean that naïvely queries its [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) property via the JDBC API.  Not as elegant, but nothing can (or should) be indefinitely backwards-compatible.  As long as I remember to clean up nicely, this should work out fine.